# Perl fire-and-forget HTTP request

Tags: perl, http, nonblocking, lwp, lwp-useragent

This is **not** the same as a background/asynchronous HTTP request.

Is there a way to fire an HTTP PUT request and not wait on response or determination of success/failure?

My codebase is single-threaded and single-process.

I'm open to monkey-patching LWP::UserAgent->request if needed.

Comment: It's not hard to find a library that allows you to perform the request without waiting for the answer, but they expect you to eventually collect the answer. Why can't you do that and just discard the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just abandon processing the response when the first data come in:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $resp = $ua->put('http://example.com/', ':content_cb' => sub { die "break early" });
print $resp->as_string;
```

You might also create a request using `HTTP::Request-new('PUT',...)->as_string`, create a socket with `IO::Socket::IP->new(...)` or (for https) `IO::Socket::SSL->new(...)` and send this request over the socket - then leave the socket open for a while while doing other things in your program.

But the first approach with the early break in the `:content_cb` is probably simpler. And contrary to crafting and sending the request yourself it guarantees that the server at least started to process your request since it started to send a response back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to alternatives to LWP, [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent) is a non-blocking user agent which allows you to control how the response is handled by the event loop when used that way. For example, as described in the cookbook, you can [change the handling of the response stream](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Guides::Cookbook#Streaming-response). This could be used to simply ignore the stream, or do something else.